# Powershell error with value as a parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I have the following script in Powershell:

```
#more code here

$CRMConn = "AuthType=AD;Url=http://${ipSolution}/${organizationName}; Domain=${domain}; Username=${username}; Password=${password}; OrganizationName=${organizationName}"

echo $CRMConn

Invoke-Command -Computername $hostnameSolution -ScriptBlock {Import-XrmSolution -SolutionFilePath "${fDrive}:\DEPLOYMENT\TCRM\CrmSolution\${solutionName}" -ConnectionString $CRMConn -PublishWorkflows $true -OverwriteUnmanagedCustomizations $true -SkipProductUpdateDependencies $true -WaitForCompletion $true -Timeout 7200 -verbose:$true} -Credential $cred
```

Whe I execute it, I get the following error (sensitive information has been modified):

> AuthType=AD;Url=http://192.168.10.53/ORGNAME; Domain=domain;
>   Username=username; Password=Password123@;
>   OrganizationName=ORGNAME
>
> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ConnectionString' because it is
>   null.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-XrmSolution], Parameter     BindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,X
>   rm.Framework.CI.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ImportXrmSolutionCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : li1appcrmf14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to pass a variable from your "outside" running script into an independent "inside" script block. i.e. you should treat Script Blocks as a completely separate independent chunk of code that should be completely self contained. If you want to pass in information or variables, you should use parameters inside the script block to do that (see @dee-see post). The only alternate way (PowerShell v3+) is to use the `$using:` scope variable ([PowerShell: Passing variables to remote commands](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-08-28-PowerShell-variables-to-remote-commands/))

```
Invoke-Command -Computername $hostnameSolution -ScriptBlock {Import-XrmSolution -SolutionFilePath "${fDrive}:\DEPLOYMENT\TCRM\CrmSolution\${solutionName}" -ConnectionString $using:CRMConn -PublishWorkflows $true -OverwriteUnmanagedCustomizations $true -SkipProductUpdateDependencies $true -WaitForCompletion $true -Timeout 7200 -verbose:$true} -Credential $cred
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$CRMConn` variable isn't visible inside your script block. You have to use the `ArgumentList` parameter of `Invoke-Command` to pass the variables to your script block.

```
Invoke-Command -Computername $hostnameSolution `
    -ScriptBlock {param($conn, $fDrive, $solutionName) Import-XrmSolution -SolutionFilePath "${fDrive}:\DEPLOYMENT\TCRM\CrmSolution\${solutionName}" -ConnectionString $conn -PublishWorkflows $true -OverwriteUnmanagedCustomizations $true -SkipProductUpdateDependencies $true -WaitForCompletion $true -Timeout 7200 -verbose:$true} ` 
    -Credential $cred `
    -ArgumentList $CRMConn, $fDrive, $solutionName
```